# Text classification preprocessing(BERT) with Tflite for Flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, data-preprocessing, tflite

I am currently working on a personal project where I am trying to integrate a text classification model with Flutter. I have successfully integrated an image classification model, but now I am encountering tokenization issues with the text classification model. The model is using the following preprocessing and encoding layers:

```py
preprocessor = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
encoder = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-cmlm/en-base/1")
```

I am unable to find a way to encode/preprocess using `tflite` package or tokenize manually as it requires a `vocab.txt` file, which I am unable to locate for the BERT model used in this case.

For more context, please see below:

**Trained Model Code**
`https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1L6i-Bx-IhxgXBOOENcE-JsoXgqZzZfvl#scrollTo=WRiJq7rg1cNr`

**Flutter Code**
`https://github.com/RevTpark/pokeDex-app`